# Two Custom Dimensions appear in collect request, but only one surfaces in reporting UI

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, custom-dimensions

I've recently implemented GA via GTM for a MediaWiki site I'm working on. As part of that configuration, I've setup custom events and variables to capture two custom dimensions (one session scope, and one hit scope respectively).

While the data layer and collect requests (e.g., google-analytics.com/collect?...&cd20=xxxx&cd44=xxxx...) show variables being set and sent, only one of the dimensions is surfaced within the GA reporting UI. More specifically, the session scoped dimension appears when slicing session-based reports, but the hit scoped dimension doesn't appear when slicing page-based reports.

Given the setup, I'd expect it would be all or none on the custom dimensions (vs. only one being captured). Has anyone run into this/any general ideas on what may be amiss?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure all expected custom dimensions are properly defined in your property settings. Undefined custom dimensions will be ignored completely.
2. You always send your data on hit. The session/user/product level dimension is about the post-processing. Therefore, for a session-level dimension, it is enough for it to be set once per session for it to appear for any hit of the session. Hit-level custom dimensions will only be available for the hits that had that dimension explicitly set for them.
3. Only 20 CDs are available for free GA. GA360 is required for more. Make sure you're sending data to a GA360 property if you want to use the 44th CD.

Comment: Thank you very much for your sharing your time and expertise here, @Cthulchu -- I really appreciate it! 

I can confirm #1 & #3 are all set (i.e., dimensions are properly defined within a GA360 property). #2 raises a really good question, particularly whether or not the dimension is being set in time. I see it in the collect request (`https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?....cd20=XXXXXXX&cd44=XXXXXXX....`), but certainly warrants another look. Thank you again and if any other thoughts come to mind, please let me know!